# Windows update doesn't show new updates

Tags: windows-7

I am using windows 7 SP1 64 bit.
Recently windows update is not showing any new updates except the old ones that are for office. The last installed update was installed on 25th july.I've using the windows update troubleshooter.
What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure there are new updates to be had?  What happens when you try to scan for new updates?  What have you tried to remedy it?  Anything in the Event Logs?  Have you tried repairing Windows Update?  How about a Windows Restore back to a point when it was working?

Comment: Yes I've checked it the microsoft website. When I scan for new updates it displays only office updates.I've used the build in windows troubleshooter.

Comment: Why do you think there should be more updates?

Comment: because the last update I've installed was released on june 10

Comment: I've got it. Updates are released on 2nd tuesday of every month. I've thought it was every tuesday. Thank you

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_Tuesday